# How to create Fragment which shows element clicked on RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm new at Android so maybe I'm just lack of understanding how things work.

So what I have right now is RecyclerView of five elements. Each of them contains figure of different shape, different fruit name and different color bar.

What I seek is to create Fragment which would show some background color, figure and fruit name inside that figure, depending on what Recyclerview element user clicks. How can I do that?

**MyAdapter class Like below:**

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<Information> data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Information> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(data.get(position).title);
        holder.relativeLayout.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(data.get(position).shape));
        holder.textView2.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(data.get(position).color));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView,textView2;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
            textView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }
}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
    public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, Data.getData(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));

}
}
```

**Fragment_layout.java**

```
public class FragmentLayout extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
}
}
```

**activity_my.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and **fragment_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_img"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an onClickListener in your ViewHolder for itemView. You can then use the adapter position to get the details you need and pass them to the new fragment you wish to display. As in the example below.

`

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements` View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textView,textView2;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
            textView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                FruitDetailFragment detailFragment = FruitDetailFragment.newInstance(fruits.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle(),
                        fruits.get(getAdapterPosition()).getcolor());

                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.my_container, detailFragment,
                        getString(R.string.fruit_detail_fragment_tag)).addToBackStack("FRUIT_DETAILS").commit();
        }
    }
```